# Namecheap Error: "Parameter common name or one of the additional domain is invalid"

Tags: ssl, csr, namecheap

Need Help!

I have been trying to reissue SSL in namecheap.com. I have already created multiple CSR using MacOS Keychain (Both from the Philippines, and from Japan) and through AWS. However, when I get to the Review & Submit part I keep getting an error (screenshot below). Thank you for any assistance with this, as I have tried numerous methods, and I still could not update the SSL.

[image: namecheap error]

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten in touch with namecheap.com, and their response is

"... the certificate has this issue due to a bug from our side that is connected to .ink TLD. ..."

It seems that this is a bug in their system.

If anybody gets this error, you might want to connect with namecheap.com, to see if this bug is still not fixed.

Comment: They probably hardcode the list of TLD and forgot to update it recently.